# Fonts and images are not found in release mode

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have web application with some content (images, fonts etc.). I tried to see how it works in Release mode and all layout crash cause fonts and images are "Not Found".

What can be cause of this behaviour and how to fix it?

What i found - My images are in folder `Content/images/`. In debug mode application find images by that path, but in Release mode it skips folder `Content/` and just try to find `images/`.

```
  body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: url(images/main_bg.jpg) repeat center top fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
```

This is how i use images in CSS

```
bundles.Add(
            new StyleBundle("~/layout-styleNew")
                .Include("~/Content/bootstrap/css/*.css")
                .Include("~/Content/bootstrap/flatly/*.css")
                .Include("~/Content/helpful.css")
                .Include("~/Content/styleNew.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/ToastMsg/css/*.css")
                .Include("~/Content/css/jquery-ui/*.css"));

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>@this.ViewBag.Title</title>

   @Scripts.Render("~/layout")
   @Styles.Render("~/layout-styleNew")
   @RenderSection("head", false)

</head>
```

Comment: Please include the code which should be including those resources..

Comment: Or give us the link of demo/site where we can check this issue.

Comment: @Leothelion, for now no demo site exists :(

Comment: No. Not the resources: how you are including them in the HTML output (so your WebForm/Razor/Html code).

Comment: @Richard, i add this css file to bundles and include it on _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

You problem in is realtive paths.

In your CSS you have:

```
background: url(images/main_bg.jpg) repeat center top fixed;
```

which means the client is looking for a folder called "images" in the same folder as the CSS. In debug this is a child of the `Content` folder where the CSS file is found.

But when you bundle, the client sees the CSS in the root folder, so creates a path relative to the root.

You need to give your bundle a name that is sufficiently similar to the real paths so retative paths are resolved correctly. Perhaps "Content/AllStyles"?

Comment: I tried this but unlucky... Client again do the same : `GET http://localhost:4715/images/main_bg.jpg 404 (Not Found)`. I have changed my bundle in next way : `bundles.Add(
    new StyleBundle("/Content/layout-styleNew")
                    .Include(...)` I tried many "modifications" with "/" and without

Comment: And should i include images into Bundle or it's not necessary?

Comment: @demo Bundling images would require changing things so the client knows which bit of the composite image to use where (see "CSS Sprites"). So no: don't bundle images.

Comment: @demo To debug this you're going to need to look at the URL the client is using for the bundle, work out the path of the image from that URL and the relative path and adjust things until they align. Your browser's dev tool's network tab will be very helpful.

Comment: This helped me solved my problem. When viewing requested path url(images/image.gif) from browser debugger. you can see request 404 to content/images where content is the name of my bundle (e.g. ~/Content/cssfile.css) but the actual location is content/somedirectory/images. What you need to do is change your bundle to ~/Content/somedirectory/cssfile.css so it would correctly map to content/somedirectory/images/image.gif